# Error with saving and retrieving image from isolated storage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, url, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to get an image from URL and save it to the isolated storage and than to get it from the isolated storage and  display it with in my WP-7 app.

Here is the relavant code:

```
public void GetImages()
{
    string uri = "http://sherutnetphpapi.cloudapp.net/mini_logos/" + path;
    WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();
    imageUri = new Uri(uri);

    m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted);
    m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(imageUri);
}

void webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    Stream stream = e.Result;
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsf.CreateFile(path);
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

        // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.

        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is at this line: `sri = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);`
I get an exception on this method `GetResourceStream()` **Expected relative Uri, found absolute.**

I dont understand what to give this method instead of the `imageUri`.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I really don't know what that is I'm new on this website. I'll be happy if you can explain me about this rate

Comment: O.k i think i got it.....thanks

Comment: When people have provided helpful answers, they get up-votes. When the answers aren't helpful, they get down-votes. Whichever answer you feel helped you the most, or was the most accurate, you need to accept it as "the correct answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you need.

```
public void GetImages()   
{   
    string uri = "http://sherutnetphpapi.cloudapp.net/mini_logos/" + path;      
    WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();   
    imageUri = new Uri(uri);   
    m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(imageUri);  
    m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted);   
    m_webClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;  

} 


void webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) 
{        
    var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isolatedfile)) 
    { 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length]; 
        while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0) 
        { 
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I get an error: "cannot convert from string to system.uri"

Comment: Yes, but i dont know what file path to give it

Comment: Chris Gessler, I get the same exception: A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.                         on the line:imageUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);

Comment: Now i get different exception:"The remote server returned an error: NotFound." on this line: byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];

Comment: I'm guessing that "path" might not be pointing to a valid image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12804/discussion-between-thechmodmaster-and-chris-gessler)

Answer (score 0):

What do this `path` contains, because if it contains an relative url, then remove `/` from path. Since you already has `/` at the end of uri.

Comment: path contains the name of a company.png , for example: cnn.png